# leave app running the background- iOS

Tags: ios, background

Is it possible to leave your app running in the background when you change applications. For example, I start my app, then i leave in the middle of a task and launch safari. After a few minutes when i go back to my app, it restarts.
How do you disable this option?

Answer (score 1):

You are not in control of when your app launches or is terminated. I suggest you read Apple's [App States and Multitasking](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html).